# Sort block devices by most recently connected?

Tags: command-line, devices, block-device, lsblk

How can I block devices by the most recent added ones?
No option in `lsblk` seems to have that functionality.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is using the `ls` command, because Linux block devices actually have a working time metadata:

`ls -lt /dev/  |grep "^b"| more`

For plain device names:

`ls -t1 /dev/  | more`

or:

`ls -lt /dev/  |grep "^b" |sed -r "s/^.* (.*)$/\1/g" | more`.

Another possible method: `lsblk -p -d --output name |tail`.
You might want to use  `lsblk -p -d --output name  /dev/sd? | tail`.

Comment: It just has one limitation: That timestamp is the **date of last modification.** We would need the date of creation, which the `stat`  command does show. But I will have to figure that out later.

Comment: USB Block devices are also sorted alphabetically: sda, sdb, sdc, sdd, sde, sdf, … `lsblk /dev/sd?
`

Comment: Another possible method: `lsblk -p -d --output name |tail
`.

Comment: Please note that Linux does not assign new devices to the next letter of the alphabet always, but to the first available one. If the last device is `/dev/sdy`, but `/dev/sde` is suddently free, `/dev/sde` will be used instead of `/dev/sdz`, making alphabetic sorting ineffective for that purpose.